# Laravel is trying to process asset requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-5.5

I have a Laravel 5.2 app and inside the public_html folder I have some assets stored in a subfolder called metronic as I am using a theme called metronic and wanted to keep it all bundled in one place to make updating it easier.

I have linked to these assets using the URL::asset() method like so:

```
<script src="{!! URL::asset('metronic/global/plugins/fullCalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js') !!}"></script>
```

This generates the following URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/metronic/global/plugins/fullCalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js
```

For some reason this is working fine locally but when I run it on my production server the request is going through Laravel. I have some middleware that checks whether or not to show the coming soon page and this is being run and so rather than the script being fetched the holding page is just being run. This is the content of the middleware:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Request;
use Route;
use Session;

class HoldingPageCheck {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(env('HOLDING_PAGE')==true && (!$request->is('coming-soon') && !$request->is('member/subscribe') && !$request->is('migrate') && !$request->is('contact') && $request->segment(1)!='admin')) {
            Session::reflash();
            return redirect(route('holding_page'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

It doesn't make any sense to me why Laravel would be interfering with an asset request it should just bypass Laravel entirely shouldn't it when a request for a JS file is made?

Comment: That really depends on your server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, it was because I was using camel case in the path to the script. Locally with xampp it didn't mind but obviously my live environment was case sensitive.